# SparkR Job 100 Minutes Timeout

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, sparkr, bigdata

I have written a bit complex sparkR script and run it using spark-submit. What script basically do is read a big hive/impala parquet based table row by row and generate new parquet file having same number of rows. 
But it seems the job stops after exactly around 100 Minutes which seems some timeout.

- For up to 500K rows script works perfectly (Because it needs less than 100 Minutes)
- For 1, 2 or 3 or more million rows script exits after 100 Minutes.

I checked all possible parameter having values 100 Minutes range I know and tested. But could not find any solution.

```
[user@localhost R]$ time spark-submit sparkr-pre.R                           
Loading required package: methods

Attaching package: ‘SparkR’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter, na.omit

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, rbind, sample, subset, summary, table, transform

15/12/30 18:04:27 WARN MetricsSystem: Using default name DAGScheduler for source because spark.app.id is not set.
[Stage 1:========================================>                 (7 + 3) / 10]Error in if (returnStatus != 0) { : argument is of length zero
Calls: write.df -> write.df -> .local -> callJMethod -> invokeJava
Execution halted
15/12/30 19:44:52 ERROR InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation: Aborting job.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job cancelled because SparkContext was shut down
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:703)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:702)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop(DAGScheduler.scala:702)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onStop(DAGScheduler.scala:1514)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop.stop(EventLoop.scala:84)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.stop(DAGScheduler.scala:1438)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$7.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1724)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1185)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1723)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$3.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:587)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHook.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:264)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:234)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:234)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:234)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1699)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:234)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:234)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:234)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.runAll(ShutdownHookManager.scala:234)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anon$2.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:216)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:54)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:567)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1824)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1837)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1914)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:140)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:138)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:933)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd(SQLContext.scala:933)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:197)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:146)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.save(DataFrame.scala:1855)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.handleMethodCall(RBackendHandler.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.channelRead0(RBackendHandler.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.channelRead0(RBackendHandler.scala:38)
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:244)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/12/30 19:44:52 ERROR DefaultWriterContainer: Job job_201512301804_0000 aborted.
15/12/30 19:44:52 ERROR RBackendHandler: save on 25 failed

real    100m30.944s
user    1m26.326s
sys     0m19.459s
```

Environment
Runtime Information

```
Name    Value
Java Home   /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_40/jre
Java Version    1.8.0_40 (Oracle Corporation)
Scala Version   version 2.10.4
Spark Properties

Name    Value
spark.akka.frameSize    1024
spark.app.id    application_1451466100034_0019
spark.app.name  SparkR
spark.driver.appUIAddress   http://x.x.x.x:4040
spark.driver.host   x.x.x.x
spark.driver.maxResultSize  8G
spark.driver.memory 100G
spark.driver.port   60471
spark.executor.id   driver
spark.executor.memory   14G
spark.executorEnv.LD_LIBRARY_PATH   $LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib64/R/lib:/usr/local/lib64:/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java/lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/lib:/usr/lib::/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native
spark.externalBlockStore.folderName spark-b60f685e-c46c-435d-ab1b-c9d1279f630f
spark.fileserver.uri    http://x.x.x.x:50281
spark.home  /datas/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6
spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max 2000M
spark.master    yarn-client
spark.org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter.param.PROXY_HOSTS  CDHPR1.dc.dialog.lk
spark.org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter.param.PROXY_URI_BASES  http://CDHPR1.dc.dialog.lk:8088/proxy/application_1451466100034_0019
spark.scheduler.mode    FIFO
spark.serializer    org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
spark.sql.parquet.binaryAsString    true
spark.submit.deployMode client
spark.ui.filters    org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
spark.yarn.dist.archives    file:/datas/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6/R/lib/sparkr.zip#sparkr
spark.yarn.dist.files   file:/home/inuser/R/sparkr-pre.R
System Properties

Name    Value
SPARK_SUBMIT    true
SPARK_YARN_MODE true
awt.toolkit sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
file.encoding   UTF-8
file.encoding.pkg   sun.io
file.separator  /
java.awt.graphicsenv    sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
java.awt.printerjob sun.print.PSPrinterJob
java.class.version  52.0
java.endorsed.dirs  /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_40/jre/lib/endorsed
java.ext.dirs   /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_40/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext
java.home   /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_40/jre
java.io.tmpdir  /tmp
java.library.path   :/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
java.runtime.name   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
java.runtime.version    1.8.0_40-b26
java.specification.name Java Platform API Specification
java.specification.vendor   Oracle Corporation
java.specification.version  1.8
java.vendor Oracle Corporation
java.vendor.url http://java.oracle.com/
java.vendor.url.bug http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
java.version    1.8.0_40
java.vm.info    mixed mode
java.vm.name    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
java.vm.specification.name  Java Virtual Machine Specification
java.vm.specification.vendor    Oracle Corporation
java.vm.specification.version   1.8
java.vm.vendor  Oracle Corporation
java.vm.version 25.40-b25
line.separator  
os.arch amd64
os.name Linux
os.version  2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64
path.separator  :
sun.arch.data.model 64
sun.boot.class.path /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_40/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_40/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_40/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_40/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_40/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_40/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_40/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_40/jre/classes
sun.boot.library.path   /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_40/jre/lib/amd64
sun.cpu.endian  little
sun.cpu.isalist 
sun.io.unicode.encoding UnicodeLittle
sun.java.command    org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit sparkr-pre.R
sun.java.launcher   SUN_STANDARD
sun.jnu.encoding    UTF-8
sun.management.compiler HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
sun.nio.ch.bugLevel 
sun.os.patch.level  unknown
user.country    US
user.dir    /home/user/R
user.home   /home/user
user.language   en
user.name   inuser
user.timezone   Asia/Colombo
Classpath Entries

Resource    Source
/datas/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6/conf/  System Classpath
/datas/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6/conf/yarn-conf/    System Classpath
/datas/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar  System Classpath
/datas/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar    System Classpath
/datas/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar    System Classpath
/datas/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-assembly-1.5.2-hadoop2.6.0.jar   System Classpath
```

spark-default.conf

```
# Default system properties included when running spark-submit.
# This is useful for setting default environmental settings.

# Example:
# spark.master                     spark://master:7077
# spark.eventLog.enabled           true
# spark.eventLog.dir               hdfs://namenode:8021/directory
# spark.serializer                 org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
# spark.driver.memory              5g
# spark.executor.extraJavaOptions  -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Dkey=value -Dnumbers="one two three"
#
spark.master            yarn-client
spark.serializer        org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
spark.driver.memory             100G
spark.executor.memory           14G 
spark.sql.parquet.binaryAsString true
spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max 2000M
spark.driver.maxResultSize      8G
spark.akka.frameSize            1024
#spark.executor.instances       16
```

I cannot share the sparkR script in public. Really sorry about that. But the code work perfectly when it needs less than 100 Minutes to complete.

Comment: Look at properties like spark.network timeout.Have a look at all possible timeouts : http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

Comment: In addition to @ravindra 's suggestion, are you collecting any RDD's to the driver, or opening any large files on the driver?  I've only seen the sparkcontext shutdown when the driver application goes down.  I see you submit in the yarn-client mode, you could possibly try submitting in the yarn-cluster mode to see if running the driver on a worker node works.  The timeout may be a config your admin has set on the server you're submitting your job from.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try your suggestions comment what happened.

Comment: Have a look at this article for further fine tuning : http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/

Comment: Cluster mode giving me an error related to configuration. I'll be able to solve it. I tried local mode and it also exits after 100 Minutes.
Further I upgrade the spark to 1.6 which released few days ago. But the issue remains same. 
I use cloudera 5.4 for hadoop. Spark 1.6 is manually installed and configured.

Comment: Some more log info

16/01/06 09:41:05 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 1
Error in if (returnStatus != 0) { : argument is of length zero
Calls: write.df -> write.df -> .local -> callJMethod -> invokeJava
Execution halted
16/01/06 10:51:40 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
16/01/06 10:51:41 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://ip:4040
16/01/06 10:51:41 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 2 failed: save at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2, took 6001.098219 s
16/01/06 10:51:41 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 3 (save at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2) failed in 6000.237 s

Comment: Did we find solution to this, we are also getting it after around 500 mins.

Comment: Not yet. Finally I processed the data batch by batch using several spark jobs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a known bug in Spark 1.6.0, see: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12609. A quick review of SparkR code also indicated that the bug is actually present since Spark 1.4.0.

Until they release a fix, the quick and dirty solution is to increase the timeout. As noted in the issue, the problematic function is `connectBackend` The function can be patched at runtime using `assignInNamespace`.

The following retrieves the original function, then wraps it in a second function for which we increase the timeout value to 48 hours. The original function is then replaced by the wrapper.

```
connectBackend.orig <- getFromNamespace('connectBackend', pos='package:SparkR')
connectBackend.patched <- function(hostname, port, timeout = 3600*48) {
   connectBackend.orig(hostname, port, timeout)
}
assignInNamespace("connectBackend", value=connectBackend.patched, pos='package:SparkR')
```

Put this code after loading the SparkR package.

The other solution would be to modify the timeout in SparkR code and recompile. For compilation instructions, see : https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/R/install-dev.sh

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll test and see.

Answer (score 0):

Since Spark 2.1, there is an environment variable called `SPARKR_BACKEND_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT` that controls the timeout. However, the default is still set to 100 minutes. So you need to set e.g. `SPARKR_BACKEND_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=1209600` on the driver so that you could run longer tasks.

I would have thought that setting `--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.SPARKR_BACKEND_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=1209600` in `spark-submit` would do the trick, but apparently that doesn't seem to set the variable properly either. So my current workaround is to include this in the R script that is being executed:

```r
Sys.setenv("SPARKR_BACKEND_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT" = 1209600)
```